# SVN list sorted by creation date

Tags: svn

If I run `svn list svn://repo.example.com/tags`, the listing is:

```
REL_1.9.0/
REL_1.9.1/
REL_1.9.10/
REL_1.9.11/
REL_1.9.12/
REL_1.9.13/
REL_1.9.14/
REL_1.9.15/
REL_1.9.16/
REL_1.9.2/
REL_1.9.3/
REL_1.9.4/
REL_1.9.5/
REL_1.9.6/
REL_1.9.7/
REL_1.9.8/
REL_1.9.9/
```

What I would like to get is:

```
REL_1.9.0/
REL_1.9.1/
REL_1.9.2/
REL_1.9.3/
REL_1.9.4/
REL_1.9.5/
REL_1.9.6/
REL_1.9.7/
REL_1.9.8/
REL_1.9.9/
REL_1.9.10/
REL_1.9.11/
REL_1.9.12/
REL_1.9.13/
REL_1.9.14/
REL_1.9.15/
REL_1.9.16/
```

So that I can get the most recent tag by tailing like this:  `svn ... | tail -1`

How can I get the tags sorted by creation date, rather than alphabetic order.

Thanks!

Comment: That's why we usually stop tags @ 9 (1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0) or with 2 digits (1.0.00, 1.0.01, ...etc)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The version of `sort` I have (cygwin) has this option

```
 -V, --version-sort          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

```
$ cat test.txt | sort -V
REL_1.9.0/
REL_1.9.1/
REL_1.9.2/
REL_1.9.3/
REL_1.9.4/
REL_1.9.5/
REL_1.9.6/
REL_1.9.7/
REL_1.9.8/
REL_1.9.9/
REL_1.9.10/
REL_1.9.11/
REL_1.9.12/
REL_1.9.13/
REL_1.9.14/
REL_1.9.15/
REL_1.9.16/
```

So give `svn list ... | sort -V | tail -1` a try