# svn tags order by committed date

Tags: svn

Can someone let me know how can I get the svn tags order by committed date.

Suppose if have svn tags like this:

```
    Project_Release_For_D_2012
    Project_Release_For_E_2012
    Project_Release_For_F_2012
    Project_Release_For_X_2012
    Project_Release_For_Y_2012
    Project_Release_For_Z_2012
```

Now after committing to SVN, I don't know which release was first, second, third etc. as they will sort according to name in the repository.

Is there a way in which I can retrieve these tags order by committed date, or order by date in between two dates.

**Its not something like, what some one tagged it as duplicate, its like this:** I have some thousands of SVN tags in repository, so I am unable to get them sorted by committed date. I didn't found the way for it yet from my all available resources.

Let me know if some one really help here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list SVN tags and its revisions from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658065/how-to-list-svn-tags-and-its-revisions-from-command-line)

Comment: Does your tags have appropriate naming? What I mean is, if they are sorted in natural order will it represent the ordering by commit date? Like you have 1.9.1 (older), 1.9.2 (newer) ?

Comment: Tags are having month and year in the every tag name, like **Project_Release_For_Samsung_March_2012**, but its not helping me get the tags in order to find my desired tag as I have almost more than 1000 tags in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log REPO-URL/tags/`

you can use -r with '{' DATE '}' parameter for limiting output (already sorted by date)

Comment: I am wondering how I have missed this command. BTW its a perfect solution, thanks @Lazy Badger.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments and help.

I have tried to follow the duplicate question tagged by nosid. Actually I didn't got what I wanted through it, but probably got a hint on how to proceed further.

After using the svn command:

```
svn ls -v ^/tags
```

**I got the large list of tags like below:** (used the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658065/how-to-list-svn-tags-and-its-revisions-from-command-line))

```
7979  ?                Apr 12  2012 AFTER_CHANGING_APPLICATION_APRIL_2012/
7970  ?                Apr 12  2012 BEFORE_CHANGING_APPLICATION_APRIL_2012/
5050  ?                Oct 05  2011 ADDING_C_FILE_OCT_2011/
2056  ?                AUG 30  2011 AETER_COMMITTING_XCHANGES_TO_PROJECT_AUG_2011/
1021  ?                APR 21  2011 AETER_COMMITTING_XCHANGES_TO_PROJECT_APR_2011/
489  ?                Dec 03  2010 AFETR_COMMITTING_BUGFIX_ON_DEC_2010/
......
```

After having this large list of SVN tags in unsorted order, now I used a simple CPP program from [here](http://uniqueminds.in/Thread-Program-for-Sorting-the-lines-in-text-file) to sort the above tags, which are stored in a text file. And got the desired result. Which is as follows:

```
 489  ?                Dec 03  2010 AFETR_COMMITTING_BUGFIX_ON_DEC_2010/
1021  ?                APR 21  2011 AETER_COMMITTING_XCHANGES_TO_PROJECT_APR_2011/
2056  ?                AUG 30  2011 AETER_COMMITTING_XCHANGES_TO_PROJECT_AUG_2011/
5050  ?                Oct 05  2011 ADDING_C_FILE_OCT_2011/
7970  ?                Apr 12  2012 BEFORE_CHANGING_APPLICATION_APRIL_2012/
7979  ?                Apr 12  2012 AFTER_CHANGING_APPLICATION_APRIL_2012/
......
```

And now I got all the tags sorted by committed date. Hope this will help to some one like me.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me to list the 10 last order by date:
svn ls ... | sort -V | tail -n 10

source [SVN list sorted by creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377692/svn-list-sorted-by-creation-date)